# What is the word for a person who thinks/afraid others can change them?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

To give some context,

A person believes somethings (for example religious practices) but if someone tries to prove that those beliefs are wrong, the person gets into defensive mode - and can even burst with anger or get ready to fight.

So, this is a person who wants to protect his/her beliefs and if someone shares their beliefs he/she thinks that they are attacking their personal beliefs. This person doesn't want to change their beliefs. They protect them with their life if needed.

FYI, in this context, belief is different than knowing things. We **know** we have two hands but don't **believe** it. [a youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3omVb8Xr184)

What is the word for such a person? (*I don't think it is believer*)

Comment: Very closely related: [What is a word for someone who wants to voice opinions but not have them challenged?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/269338/whats-a-word-for-someone-who-wants-to-voice-opinions-but-not-have-them-challeng/341193#341193) Also [What is a word for a _cannot-be-wrong_ attitude?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/107263/what-is-a-word-for-cannot-be-wrong-attitude/107271#107271) And [Word for someone that always has to be right](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55540/word-for-someone-that-always-has-to-be-right/55550#55550)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three words come to mind. Two nouns and one adjective that might conceivably be used as a noun.

> Fanatic = person who has very extreme beliefs that may lead them to behave in unreasonable or violent ways
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fanatic)

> Diehard = someone who is unwilling to change or give up their ideas or ways of behaving, even when there are good reasons to do so
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/diehard)

> Obdurate (adjective) =
> 1a : stubbornly persistent in wrongdoing. “an unrepentant, obdurate sinner”
>
> 1b : hardened in feelings “The  obdurate enemy was merciless.”
>
> 2 : resistant to persuasion or softening influences
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obdurate)

Of the three I feel that *fanatic* may suit best where religion is relevant, *diehard* in more general or secular cases. It may sometimes be possible to use obdurate as a noun but only as shorthand as in “An obdurate man” = “An obdurate”

Comment: yes, I feel "fanatic" is right. Thanks! I will wait for more possible answers.

Comment: "over-sensitive ego" or "dogmatic" could be possible words too.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest **zealot**, which Merriam-Webster defines as—

> a zealous person

*especially : a fanatical partisan*

There's also this word (adjective) for such people—

**dyed-in-the-wool**

> Thoroughgoing; out-and-out: *a dyed-in-the-wool populist.*